# Hide the persons, friends likes received on my photo, status, etc

Tags: facebook, photos, facebook-like, status

Is there a way to hide/block to my friends/public the guys/girls/etc. Who liked my photo, status but the content to remain and not to be blocked?

Answer (score 2):

No. Those who can see your content, can also see who liked them. That's how Facebook's privacy policy works.

Comment: i see..ok, thanks for the response